# How to give an ID to a KendoDropDownList created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working with a KendoGrid that looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoProject.Models.DTO.ShedDto>()
  .Name("ShedGrid")
  .EnableCustomBinding(true)
  .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu).Extra(false))
  .Columns(
      columns => {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Batch).Filterable(f =>f.UI("$.proxy (ShedGridFilter, {field: 'Batch'})"));
          columns.Bound(c => c.Shed).Filterable(f =>f.UI("$.proxy (ShedGridFilter, {field: 'Shed'}))"));
      })
  .Scrollable(s => s.Height("350px"))
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
  .AutoBind(true)
  .DataSource(datasource => datasource
  .Ajax()
  .Model(model =>
     {
        model.Id(i => i.ShedId);
        model.Field(f => f.Batch).Editable(false);
        model.Field(f => f.Shed).Editable(false);
     })
  .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.MilkFeedShed.ActionNames.MilkFeedShed_Read, MVC.MilkFeedShed.Name).Data("selectedDateGetter"))
  .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.MilkFeedShed.ActionNames.MilkFeedShed_Update, MVC.MilkFeedShed.Name).Data("selectedDateGetter"))
  .PageSize(100)
  .Batch(true)
  .Sort(s => s.Add("ChangeTime").Descending())
  )
)
```

The JavaScript for the filters is shown below:

```
function MilkFeedGridFilter(element) {
    var grid = "ShedGrid";

    var fieldName = this.field;
    var gridDataItems = $("#" + grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    var listDataItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < gridDataItems.length; i++) {
        if (gridDataItems[i][fieldName] !== null && $.inArray(gridDataItems[i][fieldName], listDataItems) < 0) {
            listDataItems.push(gridDataItems[i][fieldName]);
        }
    }
    listDataItems.sort();

        element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: {
                data: listDataItems
            }
        })

}
```

This setup creates a DropDownList in each of the KendoGrid filter columns, but I don't know how to give them a name, so that I can find them using another function later on, basically I want to translate the following into JavaScript:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("BatchDropDown");
      //.DataSource(List in JavaScript)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Added an id to the element, code is as follows:

```
function MilkFeedGridFilter(element) {
    var grid = "ShedGrid";

    var fieldName = this.field;
    var gridDataItems = $("#" + grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    var listDataItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < gridDataItems.length; i++) {
        if (gridDataItems[i][fieldName] !== null && $.inArray(gridDataItems[i][fieldName], listDataItems) < 0) {
            listDataItems.push(gridDataItems[i][fieldName]);
        }
    }
    listDataItems.sort();

    element[0].id = "BatchDropDown";    

        element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: {
                data: listDataItems
            }
        })

}
```

And I use this to select it:

```
var dropDown = $("#BatchDropDown").getKendoDropDownList();
```